# On button click get seekbar selected value

Tags: android, seekbar

**Problem:** I want to get seekbar selected value when user will click on submit button.

I have seen example codes on stackoverflow and other website but every where they are using **setOnSeekBarChangeListener** but i think in my condition i do not need to implement change listener.

I have also tried following code but it is not giving error.

```
SeekBar experience          =   (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.experience);
TextView showSelectedSkills =   (TextView)findViewById(R.id.showSelectedExperience);
showSelectedSkills.setText(experience.getProgress());
```

Is there any other method to directly show seekbar selected value or i have to use change listener?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method getProgress returns int.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html#getProgress%28%29

You are calling this method for the TextView

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText%28int%29

So it will search for a resource with that ID.

Use showSelectedSkills.setText(String.valueOf(experience.getProgress()));